# Using relative position in Outlook html message

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, css-position

I have a problem, while using Outlook to view message. My website generates emails with some html body, using relative position for some divs to make text appear over some picture.
 Every other email app displays everything correct, except of Outlook.
    
    
 Does anybody have workarounds for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `position` property is not supported by Outlook 2007 and 10 so the only solution would be to craft another style or come up with a table-based solution to support Outlook.

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx)
- [Guide to CSS support in email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/#css-com_1)

Answer (score -2):

Outlook doesn't indeed like position CSS property. But it does support `margin-left` and `margin-right`. So set margin property on your elements to move them around.

Comment: Outlook.com (formerly Hotmail) does not support the margin property. 

To have text over a background image that works across multiple email clients, you have to do a combination of inline CSS, using the "background" attribute on the containing <td> where you also set the image height, as well as using VML code. More info found here. [link](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_vector_markup_language_and_backgrounds). It can be done successfully, but it's a lot of work and takes a lot of QA.